# can't access validate props inside component - redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want to access the validate props inside the custom component,

This is my component

```
<Field name="firstName" validate={[ required() ]} label="First Name" component={MyCustomComponent} />
```

MyCustomComponent.jsx

```
function MyCustomComponent(props){

 const isRequired = props.validate

return(<div>  <span>*<span> ....  </div>)


}
```

Can't access validate props inside mycustom component.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing `Field` implementation, but I would bet that `validate` prop is not passed to `component`, that is assigned to `MyCustomComponent`

Comment: Why dont you use the validate function out of your component as shown in the documentation?